# How to Connect Database in Phonegap API for Android and iOS

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cordova

Hello I am developing application using phonegap, I want one Html page and i will put the button.

On click of that button it must fetch my sqlite3 database and just simple it must display to my next or same html page..

depending upon query.

Please anwer my question and what IDE I must use.....

Comment: ah!!!. What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

To use sqlite3 on a phonegap application, you will need this [Phonegap-SQLitePlugin](https://github.com/davibe/Phonegap-SQLitePlugin).
However, the plugin has been designed for Phonegap 1.7 so you might need to upgrade it.

Comment: the plugin is made for iOS not for android.

Comment: @LeoCai Web SQL Database is not anymore in the html5 specifications.

Comment: @poiuytrez I tested on iOS and android, but the app works well. I didn't include any plugin.

Comment: @ Leo Cai  can u please tell me how it works , means where to call and how to call the sqllite database

Comment: have you checked the doc page? I think it descripes how-to clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use any plugin, as webkit already has sqlite available. I have written a data access framework to sqlite in phonegap, please [check here](https://cordova.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20use%20nova.data).

It's quite easy to use, you don't need to write any sql scripts. It works very like asp.net entity framework.

Comment: You can also download the demo source code to see how it works.

Comment: thats really awesome work u did :)) 

See i just want one html page and on just button click it must call the sqlite database externally mine one and it must select and display to the UI html